# My variable doesn't seem to be updating within a for loop

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm working on a simple google script for a spreadsheet that will go down a column in the sheet and update the column next to it based on information pulled from links in the original column.

The problem is that the same output is being output regardless of the input column. My code is here:

```
function idThatSucka() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getRange("F2:F20");
  for (var y = 1; y <= range.getHeight(); y++) {
    var logCell = ss.getRange("E"+y+":E"+y);
    var url = ss.getRange("F"+y+":F"+y).getValue();
    if (url){
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
      Logger.log(response.getContentText());
      var theLog = Logger.getLog();
      var start = theLog.split('</title>')[0];
      var output = start.split('Steam Community :: ')[1];
      logCell.setValue(output);
    }
  }
}
```

I suspect that "url" might not be updating, but nothing I've tried so far has fixed the problem.

Comment: Well have you tried logging it to the console? right after you declare the url variable write out console.log(url);

Comment: I just tried that. No change in the output occurred.

Comment: What did the console say?

Comment: How would I go about accessing the console?

Comment: I don't remember off the top of my head how to do it in the other browsers, but in chrome, you right click. Tap inspect. Then click on console.
I found this in the spreadsheet documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger

Comment: I am using chrome. I cleared the console and then ran the script but the console remained blank.

Comment: Check out this stackoverflow for more information on the google spreadsheet Logger function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539411/how-to-debug-google-apps-script-aka-where-does-logger-log-log-to

Specifically this comment Logger.log('firstLog');MailApp.sendEmail({to:'yourEmailAddre‌​ssHere@someone.com',‌​subject: "subject here ^_^",body: Logger.getLog()});

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
function idThatSucka() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var range = ss.getRange("F2:F20");
for (var y = 1; y <= range.getHeight(); y++) {
 var url='';
 var logCell='';
   logCell = ss.getRange("E"+y+":E"+y);
   url = ss.getRange("F"+y+":F"+y).getValue();
  if (url){
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  var theLog = Logger.getLog();
  var start = theLog.split('</title>')[0];
  var output = start.split('Steam Community :: ')[1];
  logCell.setValue(output);
 }
}
}
```