# I can no longer find logs (Created by Logger) from a Google Apps script

Tags: logging, google-apps-script

I have several scripts (as WebApps) and for some of them, when I try to view the logs (Logger.log) in the execution view, it says "No logs are available for this execution".  The execution occurred within the past hour, but a similar message shows up for the executions a day or so ago.

I have scripts where logs of triggered actions seem to be viewable but not logs of WebApp executions.

I have tried following what seem to be complex instructions related to Google Cloud Platform etc, but I am an amateur at this and it used to be a simple task to view logs after an app ran, and now I don't seem to be able to do that.

Guidance will be gratefully received and I will try to follow suggestions!

Comment: Switch GCP. View>Stackdriver logging

Answer (score 2):

Logger.log will log to the exectution page only when the new default runtime is used (Chrome V8). If you disabled the new runtime Logger.log will not log to the execution page, only to the Logger logs (On the script editor click on View > Logs) but they are not persistent.

If you disabled the new runtime and want to keep the logs, replace `Logger.log` by `console.log` to log to the execution page.

Related

- [How to debug Google Apps Script (aka where does Logger.log log to?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11539411/1595451)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and suggestion. I have noticed the ChromeV8 option. One oddity is a script where there are about 20 executions and one in the middle has logs and the rest do not. There were no changes to the script during that period. So that was an example that really got me confused. I will check the latest situation during the day to see whether once it is on V8 the problem goes away.