# Google Apps Script testing unpublished Add-On

Tags: google-apps-script

So, I tried testing an unpublished by following this guide: https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/translate-addon-sample . However, after hours of trying I'm giving up because all I get is

> You’re offline.
> Check your connection and try again.

[image]

I double and triple checked everything, every authorization step, gave all the appropriate permissions, did everything in the guide, but I can't get the sample to run. No matter what I do. Given the sample is from Google themselves, can anybody give me a hint what I'm missing?

Comment: Can you confirm you are using a stable internet connection?

Comment: yes. stable internet connection. all the other add-ons work as expected.

Comment: Does this happen only for this specific add-on on your account? Do you have another test account on which perhaps you can test this? Also, from where are you accessing the add-on? (eg Docs, Sheets etc)

Comment: it works for other accounts (same domain). pretty strange ...

Comment: have you tried [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539411/how-to-debug-google-apps-script-aka-where-does-logger-log-log-to) ?