# How to view logs in a test deployment?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace-add-ons

I've not touched my Google Marketplace Add-on in several years, and it recently started failing. I've narrowed down the line number from the Logs explorer at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/ - those seem to only be error events, containing the error message and the source line. Useful, but I need more info.

I added some `Logger.log` statements to get more info (as far as I understand, it's not easy/possible to get breakpoints to trigger when you run code from an add-on). But I can't figure out (remember) where those logs are now (it used to be in the Apps Script view). I'm running the `Logger.log` version of the code via **Deploy > Test deployments** in the Apps Script project (script.google.com).

I looked at Executions (left side menu) but my Add-on has 100k+ users and I can't see "my" Test Deployment execution easily. I found the "Filter" and I can check for "Ran As: Me" and I see my failed execution, but it's just an error (the Logger message trace isn't there).

[image]

Apps Script has an Execution log button, but as far as I can tell it's only showing the execution of selected functions inside the Apps Script.

How can I see the `Logger.log` messages in a Test Deployment of an Add-on?

ETA:

- [How to debug Google Apps Script (aka where does Logger.log log to?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539411/how-to-debug-google-apps-script-aka-where-does-logger-log-log-to) is for the "legacy" Apps Script editor, which was sunset in September 2020 (apparently).
- The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75075607/1168342 gives some hints, but I still don't see my `Logger.log` messages there.

Answer (score 1):

Logging has evolved, and `Logger.log` basically only works for debugging functions in the Apps Script environment. Since my add-on is deployed in the cloud, [Cloud Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#cloud_logging) must be used.

I was finally able to get output by using `console.log` with a JSON format:

```
  console.log({message: 'inside function blah', someInfo: 15});
```

This `message` output appears in the Executions list. If you want to see the other JSON info, it's visible if you view it in **VIEW IN CLOUD LOGGING** (button on the right).

[image]

It is also possible to just do `console.log("hello");` without using JSON.